# Using \newenvironment in rmarkdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I am trying to create a codebook-style environment in an Rmarkdown document, as shown below:

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_crop: yes
    keep_tex: no
    number_sections: yes
    citation_package: biblatex
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
header-includes:
- \usepackage[english]{babel}
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{caption}
- \usepackage{physics}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{tocloft}
- \usepackage{inputenc}
- \usepackage{setspace}
- \usepackage{tabularx}
- \usepackage{lipsum}
- \usepackage{listings}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{mathtools}
- \usepackage{lscape}
- \usepackage{rotating}
- \usepackage{epstopdf}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \geometry{letterpaper, portrait, margin=1in}
- \hypersetup{colorlinks = false, linkbordercolor = {white}, citebordercolor = {white},
  urlbordercolor = {white}}
- \lstset{language=R, basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,stringstyle=\color{DarkGreen},otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character}, keywordstyle=\color{blue}, commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen}}
fontsize: 14pt
---

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\doublespacing

\newpage

Defining function here:

\newlength\cbl
\newenvironment{codebook}[1][]{
    \settowidth{\cbl}{#1}
    \parskip1em plus .3em minus .2em
    \parindent0pt
    \def\code##1##2{{\bfseries ##1}\hfill
        \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-15em-\cbl}{##2}\par}}{\noindent}

\newpage

\singlespacing

Testing out the environment here: 

\subsubsection{Codebook}
    
\begin{codebook}
  \code{country}{Country name.}
  \code{year}{Year of country observation.}
  \code{codename}{Country code (character).}
  \code{codenumber}{Country code (numeric).}
\end{codebook}
```

I have confirmed that the `\newenvironment` code works correctly in TeXstudio, but when I try to knit this document to a PDF, I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \code
```

I assume that there is something within the `\newenvironment` command that doesn't work well with rmarkdown syntax. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `keep_tex: yes` in the YAML, you can get a hint about what has gone wrong.  Starting with `\subsubsection{Codebook}`, you'll see

```
\subsubsection{Codebook}

\settowidth{\cbl}{\code}
    \parskip 1em plus .3em minus .2em
    \parindent 0pt
    \def\code#\code#
```

So what has happened is that Pandoc has tried to process
your environment definition instead of leaving it alone.  You can force it to ignore the definition by entering it like this:

````
```{=latex}
\newlength\cbl
\newenvironment{codebook}[1][rob\_avprison1]{
    \settowidth{\cbl}{#1}
    \parskip1em plus .3em minus .2em
    \parindent0pt
    \def\code##1##2{{\bfseries ##1}\hfill
        \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-15em-\cbl}{##2}\par}}{\noindent}
```
````

This appears to be enough in your minimal example, but you might need to wrap more stuff in the real document.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for the minimum example and the full document. Much appreciated.